# Spaces in FOR /F and RD loop in .BAT file using text file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd, rd

Can you help me solve an unusual issue with CMD trailing space lines. I've written a simple batch script for removing folder paths listed in a file. Command:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%p in (paths.txt) do rd /s %%p
```

I've put a test path name string into the `path.txt`:

```
\\sample path
```

Unfortunately, when the script runs it splits contents of a file into two lines and treat separately `\\sample` and `path`. However if I use `ECHO` instead of `RD` it reads whole lines regardless of the spaces.

How do I force `RD /S` command to ignore spaces? I also don't want to use double quotes for the folder path in the text file.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims=" %%p in (paths.txt) do rd /s "%%p"
```

Place quotes in the `rd` command enclosing the retrieved path